# Liferay-Portlets in Drupal

Tags: drupal, liferay, portlet, jsr286

We have some portlets which are JSR 286 complaint. We sell those portlets with a liferay-server to our customers. One customer asked  if it's possible to use those with  Drupal instead of Liferay.

I can not find any information that Drupal supports jsr-286-portlets. So its not possible to use the liferay-portlets with Drupal, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have the following options:

### Web Service for Remote Portlets 2.0 (WSRP)

Quoting from WSRP specification:

> The Web Services for Remote Portlets specification defines a web
>   service interface for accessing and interacting with interactive
>   presentation-oriented web services.

Basically you need a running instance of Liferay exposing your portlets as presentation-oriented web service to Drupal that will consume them and send back to the client.

The good news is that Drupal seems to support it. You need to enable **Drupal** as a **consumer** of [WSRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_for_Remote_Portlets), see [**that**](http://drupal.org/project/wsrp) Drupal page, and **Liferay** as a **producer**, see [**here**](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/WSRP).

### Using IFrame

Similar to first solution but with less integration and more work to do about security because the client will contact directly the Liferay server, so you'll need to expose it as a public server (if not in a Intranet scenario) and you'll probably need a **[Single Sign On](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on&ei=3XKiUNLIBuis0AHH-4HICw&usg=AFQjCNEssO08IAUl2mZrnBk9p5XtFiqGLg&sig2=YFpFtX2ApzvKxoPFpR-d-Q)** solution for authentication.

---

I suggest to take a look at that document about [**Liferay Application Integration Strategies**](http://dev.opnworks.com/downloads/soft/Liferay/Documentation/Liferay%20Application%20Integration%20Strategies.pdf) because recap very well several integration strategies with pros and cons (including the two I cited).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, especially the Liferay Application Integration Strategy-Document is very helpful! It seems to me that its not as easy to integrate a Liferay-Portlet in Drupal as i thought... or hoped...

My personal conclusion is, that its not worth trying it and it seems that there are too many problems (because of the higher complexity) we may have to deal with!